# Spring Data JPA transaction and async not working

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

I have a saveAudit fucntionality with Spring Data Jpa(version 2.3.3) that i want to make  asynchronous but data is not saved in table when asyn annotation is used.

Please find below my config below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mu.dummy.common.audit")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {AuditRepository.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Audit.class})
public class JpaTestConfig {
}
```

My async bean is defined below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {
    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Based on the online resource i saw that async cannot be used in the same class where there is transactional annotation, so I have created a class to define the async method:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmptClass implements EmpI {

    private final AuditService auditService;
   

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void callSave(AuditDto auditDto) {
        auditService.saveAudit(auditDto);
       

    }
}
```

Then I call the impl class as shown below:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditServiceImpl implements AuditService {

    private final AuditRepository auditRepository;
    private final AuditMapper auditMapper;

    public List<AuditDto> findByClientId(Integer clientId) {
        return auditMapper.mapListAuditToListAuditDTO(auditRepository.findByClientId(clientId));
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveAudit(AuditDto auditDto) {

        System.out.println("start saveAudit");

        auditRepository.save(auditMapper.mapAuditDtoToAudit(auditDto));
       

    }
```

When I run my integration test below:

```
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaTestConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AuditServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    AuditService auditService;
    @Autowired
    AuditRepository auditRepository;
    @Autowired
    empI empI;

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void saveAudit_Ok() {

        AuditDto auditDto = new AuditDto();
        auditDto.setColumnName("Assesment table Mapper 1");
        auditDto.setColumnValue("Assesment value");
        auditDto.setCreatedBy("test");
        auditDto.setTableName("Table Assesment");
        auditDto.setCreatedOn(new Date());
        auditDto.setClientId(6);
        auditDto.setRemark("updated because of");
        System.out.println("---------------------start saveAudit test");
        auditService.saveAudit(auditDto);
        
        System.out.println("-------------------end saveAudit test");
    }
```

When the above method is called no records is saved in db but when I remove the Async annotation it is saved successfully.

Please can anyone tell me what i am missing here?

Comment: Are you using Springboot? Do you have the @EnableTransactionManagement set?

Comment: I guess your callSave should be in AsyncConfig class, rather then having in Component class.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I have added my config to scan pakages above. yes it is a spring boot project but without the @SpringBootAnnotation because i will pakage this project as a jar and other project will embed this audit jar for auditing purpose

Comment: the save is async, you have to at least give it some time, before the test ends and I assume stops all executors.

Comment: Thanks a lot you were right I ve added this Thread.sleep(10000); after calling save in the test and it worked